# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ' generateBackendFunction')

Tags: reactjs, node.js, plugins, strapi, koa

I'm trying create a plugin that serve to strapi community to have ready backend post request function of the content type.

`src/server/code-generation/generateBackendFunction.js`:

```js
'use strict';

// Import required modules
const Mustache = require('mustache');

// Define the generateBackendFunction function
async function generateBackendCode(model, method) { 
    // Sample model schema
    const modelSchema = {
        kind: 'collectionType',
        collectionName: 'blogs',
        attributes: {
            Title: { type: 'string', required: true, maxLength: 20 },  
            Description: { type: 'string', required: true },
            image: { type: 'string', required: true },
            Sujet: { type: 'string' },
        },  
    };

    // Sample HTTP request type
    const requestType = 'POST';

    // Define a template for the backend function
    const template = `
        module.exports = {
            async handle{{RequestType}}Request(ctx) {
                const { {{Attributes}} } = ctx.request.body;
                try {
                    // Add your business logic here
                    // e.g., create a new blog entry in the database
                    const newBlog = await strapi.services.blog.create({ {{Attributes}} });
                    ctx.send(newBlog);
                } catch (error) {
                    ctx.throw(500, 'Error handling {{RequestType}} request', { error });
                }
            },
        };
    `;

    // Extract attribute names from the model schema
    const attributes = Object.keys(modelSchema.attributes);

    // Render the template with the extracted attributes and request type
    const renderedCode = Mustache.render(template, {
        RequestType: requestType.toUpperCase(),
        Attributes: attributes.join(', '),
    });

    // Return the rendered code
    return renderedCode;
}

// Export the generateBackendFunction function`  
module.exports = generateBackendCode;
```

`src/server/controllers/GenerateBackendFuntion.js`:

```js
'use strict';

const generateBackendCode = require('…/code-generationgenerateBackendFunction'); // Corrected import

module.exports = {
    async generateBackendFunction(ctx) {
        try {
            const { model, method } = ctx.request.body;
            const backendCode = await generateBackendCode(model, method);
            ctx.send({ backendCode });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error generating backend code:', error);
            ctx.throw(500, 'Internal server error');
        }
    }
};
```

`src/server/routes/index.js`:

```js
{  
    method: “POST”,
    path: “/api/generate-backend-function”,
    handler: “GenerateBackendFunction.generateBackendFunction”,
    config: {
        auth: false
    }`
}
```

But when I run `npm run develop` I get this error:

> ⠦ Loading Strapi[ERROR] There seems to be an unexpected error, try again with --debug for more information

> TypeError: Error creating endpoint POST /api/generate-backend-function: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'generateBackendFunction')  at getAction (C:\Users\USER\Downloads\StrapiGen=master 1\StrapiGen=master\StrapiGEN\node_mo  dules@strapi\strapi\dist\services\server\compose-endpoint.js:104:24) at C:\Users\USER\Downloads\StrapiGen=master 1\StrapiGen=master\StrapiGEN\node_modules@stra  pi\strapi\dist\services\server\compose-endpoint.js:56:22  at createRoute (C:\Users\USER\Downloads\StrapiGen=master 1\StrapiGen=master\StrapiGEN\node_ modules@strapi\strapi\dist\services\server\routing.js:71:5)  at C:\Users\USER\Downloads\StrapiGen=master 1\StrapiGen=master\StrapiGEN\node_modules@stra pi\strapi\dist\services\server\routing.js:80:9  at Array.forEach ()  at Object.addRoutes (C:\Users\USER\Downloads\StrapiGen=master 1\StrapiGen=master\StrapiGEN\  node_modules@strapi\strapi\dist\services\server\routing.js:78:21)  at Object.routes (C:\Users\USER\Downloads\StrapiGen=master  1\StrapiGen=master\StrapiGEN\node_modules@strapi\strapi\dist\services\server\api.js:20:20)  at Object.routes (C:\Users\USER\Downloads\StrapiGen=master 1\StrapiGen=master\StrapiGEN\nod  e_modules@strapi\strapi\dist\services\server\index.js:52:27)  at registerPluginRoutes (C:\Users\USER\Downloads\StrapiGen=master 1\StrapiGen=master\Strapi GEN\node_modules@strapi\strapi\dist\services\server\register-routes.js:43:21)  at registerAllRoutes (C:\Users\USER\Downloads\StrapiGen=master 1\StrapiGen=master\StrapiGEN \node_modules@strapi\strapi\dist\services\server\register-routes.js:20:3) `